# clang-format: Align asterisk (*) of pointer declaration with variable name

Tags: clang, clang-format

I am using the following options in my `.clang-format` file:

```
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
PointerAlignment: Right
```

The current formatting result is the following:

```
char *         var1;
SomeOtherType *var2;
int            var3;
```

The result I was expecting would be:

```
char          *var1; //note the changed position of * 
SomeOtherType *var2;
int            var3;
```

How can I configure `clang-format` to align the asterix (*) with the variable name rather then with the type when I am
using the `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fixed now!

The review https://reviews.llvm.org/D27651 has been re-applied in https://reviews.llvm.org/D103245 and committed in https://reviews.llvm.org/rG3e333cc82e42e1e2ecc974d896489eebe1a5edc2.

This change will be included in LLVM 13 release.

Comment: Hi Marek, It doesn't work for me. I am using clang-format 13.0.0. I use "PointerAlignment: Right", but the asterisk is still aligned to the left - to the type name.

Comment: Alexey, you should report a bug then. https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/labels/clang-format

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu Focal with Clang-format 12 does not do "Right" but Emacs with `lsp-mode` with `clangd` and `clang-format` 13 does.

Answer (score 29):

`PointerAlignment: Right` is unfortunately not implemented yet.

See https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/lib/Format/WhitespaceManager.cpp#L643

```
void WhitespaceManager::alignConsecutiveDeclarations() {
  if (!Style.AlignConsecutiveDeclarations)
    return;

  // FIXME: Currently we don't handle properly the PointerAlignment: Right
  // The * and & are not aligned and are left dangling. Something has to be done
  // about it, but it raises the question of alignment of code like:
  //   const char* const* v1;
  //   float const* v2;
  //   SomeVeryLongType const& v3;

  AlignTokens(Style, [](Change const &C) { return C.IsStartOfDeclName; },
              Changes);
}
```

Comment: This is still applicable. Wondering if it will be fixed at all?

Comment: I wonder what happened to https://reviews.llvm.org/D27651, it has implemented right alignment back in 2016.

Comment: Still not implement in clang-format 13.0.0